# I am getting an error that the expression in my Access Query is too complex

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010, ms-query

```
 SELECT dbo_job.job_date, 
        dbo_job.job, 
        dbo_job.suffix, 
        dbo_job.item, 
        qry_SumCost.SumMatlPlan, 
        qry_SumCost.SumMatlAct, 
        ([qty_released]*[fixovhd_rate])/[pcs_per_lbr_hr] AS lbr_cost_plan,       
        qry_LaborHours.fixovhd_t_lbr, 
        [fixovhd_t_lbr]/[qty_complete] AS [FG Actual Price]
  FROM  qry_SumCost 
  INNER JOIN (dbo_job 
      INNER JOIN qry_LaborHours 
          ON (dbo_job.job = qry_LaborHours.job) 
          AND (dbo_job.suffix = qry_LaborHours.suffix)) 
       ON (qry_SumCost.job_date = dbo_job.job_date) 
       AND (qry_SumCost.job = dbo_job.job) 
       AND (qry_SumCost.suffix = dbo_job.suffix)
   GROUP BY dbo_job.job_date, 
            dbo_job.job, 
            dbo_job.suffix, 
            dbo_job.item, 
            qry_SumCost.SumMatlPlan, 
            qry_SumCost.SumMatlAct, 
            ([qty_released]*[fixovhd_rate])/[pcs_per_lbr_hr],                
            qry_LaborHours.fixovhd_t_lbr, 
            [fixovhd_t_lbr]/[qty_complete]
     HAVING (((dbo_job.job_date) Between [Forms]![MainForm]![Text2] 
                                        And [Forms]![MainForm]![Text6]) 
              AND ((dbo_job.job) Like "BM0*" 
                  Or (dbo_job.job)     Like "WT0*"));
```

When I remove the expression [fixovhd_t_lbr]/qty_complete] it works fine, but when I include it it gives me the error "This expression is typed incorrectly, or its is too complex to be evaluated. For example, a numeric expression may contain too many complicated elements. Try simplifying the expression by assigning parts of the expression to variables." I don't see how this could be considered complex. Both of the elements of that expression are directly from two different tables and are NOT expressions themselves (in case anyone was wondering). I am positive it is due to this because by process of elimination I stumbled upon this being the problem.

Comment: @Alan Stallwood thanks for the edit, couldn't figure out how to do that haha...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query doesn't make sense.  You are using `group by`, but have no aggregation functions.  This means that the conditions in the `having` clause can be moved to a `where` clause and you can use `select distinct` instead.

So, perhaps this will fix your problem:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT dbo_job.job_date, 
        dbo_job.job, 
        dbo_job.suffix, 
        dbo_job.item, 
        qry_SumCost.SumMatlPlan, 
        qry_SumCost.SumMatlAct, 
        ([qty_released]*[fixovhd_rate])/[pcs_per_lbr_hr] AS lbr_cost_plan,       
        qry_LaborHours.fixovhd_t_lbr, 
        [fixovhd_t_lbr]/[qty_complete] AS [FG Actual Price]
  FROM  qry_SumCost INNER JOIN
        (dbo_job INNER JOIN
         qry_LaborHours 
         ON (dbo_job.job = qry_LaborHours.job) AND
            (dbo_job.suffix = qry_LaborHours.suffix)
       ) 
       ON (qry_SumCost.job_date = dbo_job.job_date) AND
          (qry_SumCost.job = dbo_job.job) AND
          (qry_SumCost.suffix = dbo_job.suffix)
WHERE (((dbo_job.job_date) Between [Forms]![MainForm]![Text2] And
                                   [Forms]![MainForm]![Text6]) And
        ((dbo_job.job) Like "BM0*" Or (dbo_job.job) Like "WT0*"));
```